# User State from OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync (.Net Core, Botframework, Microsoft Teams)

Tags: .net, .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to authenticate users in Teams App (from Messaging Extensions Submitting action).

In [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config) I've founded that Auth flow begins in `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync`, but I need to authenticate users from `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync` (`Submit` action).

Everything is fine, but I can't access User's `State` to understand is user authenticated and then get the token for using Graph.
`OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync` receives `MessagingExtensionQuery` as action, which has a `State` property.
But `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync` receives `MessagingExtensionAction` as as action, which hasn't `State` property.

I've tried to get it through

```
            var state = turnContext.TurnState.Get<string>("State");
```

but it isn't seems to work. I didn't found any other options to get `State`.

Auth page opens and works fine (I can approve app).

Can you tell how to get it? Or how to auth users from submit action?
Thank you.

Full method below:

```
protected override async Task<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, MessagingExtensionAction action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var magicCode = string.Empty;
    var state = turnContext.TurnState.Get<string>("State"); // always null
    // var state = action.State - in sample
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state)) 
    {
        int parsed = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(state, out parsed))
        {
            magicCode = parsed.ToString();
        }
    }
    var tokenResponse = await(turnContext.Adapter as IUserTokenProvider).GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext, _connectionName, magicCode, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    if (tokenResponse == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenResponse.Token))
    {

        var signInLink = await(turnContext.Adapter as IUserTokenProvider).GetOauthSignInLinkAsync(turnContext, _connectionName, cancellationToken);

        return new MessagingExtensionActionResponse
        {
            ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
            {
                Type = "auth",
                SuggestedActions = new MessagingExtensionSuggestedAction
                {
                    Actions = new List<CardAction>
                    {
                        new CardAction
                        {
                            Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                            Title = "Authorization",
                            Value = signInLink,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        };
    }

<<remaining code>>
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, is it not possible for you to set in the payload sent to the submit? In the action there is a data field that you can leverage to set your own data